# access to loki in grafana cloud

Tags: grafana, grafana-loki

I just decided to try out grafana cloud and especially loki for this. Therefore I just set up to push my nextcloud logs for first experiments.
The push seems to be working, at least I see an ingest rate at the account dashboard.

Now I would like to explore the logs but don't have any clue where. Maybe I'm missing some links - how can I access the logs now? Is there any URL to access the ingested logs?

Same question will probably arise to access the provided prometheus instance.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, Grafana is the "UI" for Loki, so you need some Grafana instance.

You very likely has also your Grafana instance in Grafana Cloud, where is your Loki datasource preconfigured, so you can explore logs there (with explore Grafana feature for example).

Or your Loki overview in the Grafana Cloud has `Grafana Data Source settings`, which you can use to configure Loki datasource in any other Grafana instance (e.g. you can start own Grafana instance locally).